# Adding a scrollbar to a Frame, frame keeps ex expanding and scroll down't work

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to add a scrollbar to a widget in the middle of my frame.

I can add the scrollbar but as I populate the widget it just expands and the scroll bar doesn't scroll the contents, image below. This is one of those days where I have tried everything I can find online but just can't get it working.

[image]

Here is my code,

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font

window = Tk()
window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 600)) #Width x Height
window.configure(background="White")


###############
# Page 1
###############

nb = ttk.Notebook(window)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=50, rowspan=50, sticky='NESW')
helv36 = tkinter.font.Font(family='Helvetica', size='12')


page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='Orders')


top_frame2 = Frame(page1, width=450, height=10, pady=3)
Label (top_frame2 , text='Top Frame',  fg="black", anchor='w', 
relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")


center2 = Frame(page1, bg='gray', width=50, height=40, padx=3, pady=3)
btm_frame2 = Frame(page1, bg='white', width=450, height=45, pady=3)
Label (btm_frame2 , text='bottom frame',  fg="black", anchor='w', 
relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")

top_frame2.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
center2.grid(row=1, sticky="ew")
btm_frame2.grid(row=3, sticky="ew")

text = Text(center2,height=7)
textscr = Scrollbar(center2)
text.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=4,sticky=E+W)
textscr.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=4,sticky=N+S)
center2.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
center2.columnconfigure(1,weight=0)
#Sample Data
Label (text, text='product 1 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 2 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 3 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 4 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price  ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 4 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 5 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 6 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 7 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 8 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 9 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 10 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 11 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label (text, text='product 12 | Description Description Description Description Description |  Price Price Price ',  fg="black", anchor='w', relief="groove", bg="White", font=helv36).grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")

###############
# Page 2
###############
page2= ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page2, text='Weights')


###############
# Page 3
###############
page3= ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page3, text='Other')


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tkinter ` can't scroll `Frame`. You have to put `Frame` on `Canvas` and scroll Canvas. Or simply search on internet examples with `Scrolled Frame` which use this method.

Comment: Thanks I'll rework it.